# Getting audio information from PCM data

Tags: c#, audio, frequency, pcm

I've never been able to understand how audio data is stored.  However, I'd like to know a way to find the pitch of PCM data.  Let's say, for example, that I recorded a single key being striked on a piano, in 16-bit mono PCM format at a given sample rate.  How could I find the frequency, in hertz, of the audio?  Simple code to get the average frequency works for me, but a more detailed explanation of how to better understand the format would be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PCM audio is not stored as a series of pitches.  To figure that up, you need a Fast Fourier Transform, or FFT.  See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pitch+detection, there are 10s of posts about this already.

Think of a audio waveform.  PCM encoding is simply sampling that wave a certain number of times per second, and using a specific number of bits per sample.

[image: Waveform]

Image from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation

16-bit Mono PCM at 44.1kHz means that 44,100 times per second, a 16-bit value (2 bytes) will be stored that represents the waveform at the specific time the sample was taken.  44.1kHz is fast enough to store frequencies that approach 22kHz (see [Nyquist Frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)).

FFT turns those samples from the time domain to the frequency domain.  That is, you can find what the levels of all the frequencies are for a particular period of time.  The more bands you look at, the more computational intensive it is.

Comment: Thanks! I've been tearing my hair out over this for a while, audio storage is usually a closed door to me.

Comment: So I was able to implement code I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FftGuitarTuner.aspx), but I get inaccurate results. For instance, when playing middle C on a piano (both virtually and in the real world), it reports the frequency as approximately 484 Hz, when in reality a middle C is closer to 261 Hz.  Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: @Drew: pitch detection is quite tricky - most musical instruments have complex power spectra and often the fundamental is not the strongest component - the ear "fills in" the fundamental pitch based on information from the harmonics. Search SO for "pitch detection" as there are already a lot of questions with good answers on this whole subject.

Comment: @Drew, I recommend spending some time looking at a spectrum analyzer to get a better idea of what you are looking at.  Unless you are looking at sine waves, what you hear is actually made up of many pitches that give the sound its sonic characteristics, such as timbre.  Psychoacoustics comes into play.